# How to handle CSV file where address column data's are seperated by comma as a single column instead of multiple column in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-csv

If I have incoming data for address field in CSV file is seperated by comma(','), how can I handle this in Spark?
If I want that data as record to my address column.

Example-Suppose I have input data in form of CSV file as below,

```
Bob,Delhi,NCR,8984124789
Scott,Bangalore,Karnataka,9040788301
Robert,Andheri,Mumbai,Maharastra,9338075922
```

I want final dataframe as,

```
Name   Address                    MobileNo
Bob    Delhi,NCR                  8984124789
Scott  Bangalore,Karnataka        9040788301
Robert Andheri,Mumbai,Maharastra  9338075922
```

How can we can handle this in Spark?

Comment: Please take a look at this and see if you can apply it using python: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60965746/5761558

Comment: Change your delimiter something else other than the delimiter inside your address column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an RDD to clean up the data before making a data frame from it:

```
rdd = sc.textFile('path-to-csv.csv')
```

Then clean it up by shifting the last column in order to isolate the `Address` data to the end of the line:

```
df = rdd.map(lambda l: l.split(','))\
        .map(lambda l: Row(Name=l[0],Mobile=l[-1],Address=', '.join(l[1:-1])))\
        .toDF()
```

And to explicitly set the schema:

```
df = rdd.map(lambda l: l.split(','))\
    .map(lambda l: Row(Name=l[0],MobileNo=l[-1],Address=', '.join(l[1:-1])))\
    .toDF(schema=StructType(fields=[StructField('Name',StringType()),
                                    StructField('Address', StringType()),
                                    StructField('MobileNo', StringType())]))
```

The result:

```
+------+---------------------------+----------+
|Name  |Address                    |MobileNo  |
+------+---------------------------+----------+
|Bob   |Delhi, NCR                 |8984124789|
|Scott |Bangalore, Karnataka       |9040788301|
|Robert|Andheri, Mumbai, Maharastra|9338075922|
+------+---------------------------+----------+
```

Comment: compared to the other wrong answer above, this is a nice answer. Clearly, the obvious issue is to generate such a weird and imo ill-formed CSV instead of either wrapping column values inside quotes " " or using a different separator like TSV

Comment: @UninformedUser Good point. This should only be done if changing the delimiter is impossible. I also thought one could just move bits of substrings before using `read.csv` on a dataset, but pyspark doesn't seem to have such an option (unlike scala or java). Would be nice to see if someone knows of such an alternative (to splitting into unnecessary lists when one can move substrings followed by a powerful spark.read.csv...)